# Jupyter Notebook not executing cells?

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook

I installed jupyter notebook using a pip. But when I launch jupyter using command prompt it is not executing cells. Here are some of the screenshots:

[image: command line]

[image: web browser].

While inspecting the browser I found two warnings:

[image: warning]

[image]

Further if I reload the webpage it is taking a long time.

Can anyone help me out here?

Comment: it looks like you have not executed the cell, select the cell and pre cntrl enter to execute the cell.

Comment: Does it work in the terminal, with ipython ?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like your notebook is not able run python-3 kernel. Can you try selecting python-2 from the dropdown and try rerunning your notebook?